# Защита лайков от накрутки, localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла небольшая проблема. Ниже приведен скрипт, который обрабатывает клик на кнопку лайк и затем создает объект в `localStorage` + делает кнопку лайк неактивной. По идее, при следующем клике скрипт должен проверять наличие объекта `'like'` в `localStorage` и если он там есть, оставлять кнопку неактивной, но как всегда что-то пошло не так и при каждом обновлении старницы кнопку лайк все еще можно кликать.

```
    $('.likes-button').click(function () {

            if (localStorage.getItem("like" === true)) {
                $('.likes-button').attr("disabled", true).css({
                      'cursor': 'default', 
                      'color': 'gray'
                });
        }


      var bkid;
      bkid = $(this).attr("data-ansid");
      $.get('/add_like/', {book_id: bkid}, function (data) {
        $('#like_count').html(data);
        $('.likes-button').attr("disabled", true).css({
              'cursor': 'default', 
              'color': 'gray'
        });
        var store = localStorage.setItem("like", "already");

    });
});
```

Comment: Это в любом случае не будет являться защитой от накрутки

Comment: Ок, попробую через cookie тогда.

Comment: куки тоже в любом случае не будут являться защитой от накрутки

Comment: думаю, в моем случае и этого хватит

Comment: Куки чистить даже проще чем localStorage :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без авторизации пользователя Вы не сделаете 100% защиту от накрутки.
Есть некоторые вещи, которые могут просто улучшить защиту,
К примеру js библиотека fingerprint, настроив ее - у каждого посетителя так сказать будет свой идентификатор в конкретном браузере.
Еще есть supercookie, правда они теряют свою силу после ухода flash в прошлое.

Но это все защита от дурака )

Answer (score 1):

Ваш обработчик срабатывает только после нажатия на кнопку. Если загрузить страницу ещё раз, то он не срабатывает. Сделайте проверку при загрузки страницы и выключайте кнопку в ней. Но это не спасёт от накруток.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что данные могут быть удалены из localStorage?

Comment: @Bootuz я имею ввиду, что для накрутки будут использовать curl/wget и на прямую делать get/post.

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman, у меня сейчас скрипт на VPS так голоса племяннику накручивает в конкурсе НГ костюмов ))) На сайте тупо по IP защита.